Problems after successful first Benchy - Failed prints with same configuration (Anet A8)
I’m using an Anet A8 and recently printed my first Benchy successfully. The first print came out really well, but now, with the exact same configuration, all I get are failed prints. I’ve attached some pictures of the failed prints.
Here’s the configuration I used:

Filament: PLA
Print temperature: 200 °C
Bed temperature: 60 °C
Print speed: 50 mm/s
Layer height: 0.2 mm
Retraction: 5 mm at 50 mm/s
Infill: 15%
Cooling: 100%


As mentioned, the first Benchy printed perfectly, but now I’m getting layer issues, poor layer adhesion, or under-extruded areas. Has anyone experienced this before? What could be causing this sudden poor print quality even though I didn’t change anything in the settings? What should I check or adjust?

I try to add Images but it wint Work

@Velvet yes i Print a few benchys to make Sure.
